# Azure App Service library for iOS apps (not Xamarin iOS) to work with Azure Push Notification Hubs, now that Mobile App Services is deprecated

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

Now that Microsoft has deprecated Mobile App Services iOS SDK, which is referenced in some of their examples (1.2.4 vs. last 2.2.2), and is transitioning to Azure App Service, there is no clear explanation of what to link to a Swift4 (or Objective-C) Xcode 9 project to modify for the Notification hub name and ListenSharedAccess URL.  Please advise with example code an reference documents.  This is for iOS app push notification with Azure Notification Hubs as connecting with the backend to register tokens etc., not Xamarin iOS (for which there is an example on MSFT site).

Answer (score 0):

The [iOS SDK for Azure Mobile Apps](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-ios-client) has recently been updated to v3.4.0.

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-push) has instructions for adding push notifications to your Mobile Apps project. I would recommend the iOS app not know anything directly about your notification hub, but instead send the device's push token to your App Service, which in turn can register the device with the notification hub.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for your reply But I believe that I did already update the iOS SDK for Azure Mobile Apps to v3.4.  It is very confusing because Xamarin documents still reference the old deprecated libraries for Mobile Service SDK for iOS and even that was old (last was 2.2.2).

Comment: I did finally understand the MSFT Azure approach that you mention here (iOS app interfacing to a backend Azure App Service Server-Side component BUT There is Very Unclear or Confusing of How/Where to Write/Add what should be a Standard "Turn/Wraparound template" for the Push Notification passing of the Token to the Notification Hub.  In other words, the Only Examples REFERENCE an Example that is ALSO doing Database Write updating, that invokes an automatic Notification on each record addition or modification (which Confuses the Simple Std use case).

Comment: I believe Many people, including a friendly European dev who shared his iOS Swift code to interface with Notification Hubs, MAY STILL be using the old deprecated iOS SDK for Mobile Services WAY of CONNECTING to Azure Notification Hub (Directly(?), vs the method that you outline and MSFT Azure is apparently recommending.

Comment: I did Not implement the Database example's Server-Side code, but Still hope that at Least the Test Send Azure operation would work, given that I need Fully Invoke and Setup the Azure App Service Mobile App in the Portal, and connect the Push entry to the Notification Hub and SharedListenURL, but Nothing Worked.

Comment: I resorted to the OpenSource PUSHER, and I immediately could send Multiple Immediate push notifications to my iOS devices by typing in the 64Hexchar TokenID that Xamarin debugging showed, and entering iOS JSON notification text, to the Xcode Developer certificate P12 file for the iOS app setup at developer.apple.com  Thanks

Comment: Your Reference Link (is exactly pointing to the Convoluted Mixed Up Example tied to the Autoupdating Database Table Server-side example).

Comment: Please have someone create example FOR ONLY ROUTING iOS app Device Token to Azure App Service Mobile Apps backend To Do ONLY This Operation, NOTHING ELSE, to register it with Notification Hubs, and then hopefully it will finally show up and Test Send will work.

Comment: (This page) has instructions for adding push notifications to your Mobile Apps project.   ... where (This Page) is Pointing to the Convoluted MIXED-UP Example

Comment: Hi, I don't work at Microsoft; I have to try to make sense of their docs too. They are usually good about answering Stack Overflow questions so hopefully someone will chime in. Are you still having issues with push notifications? If so please update your question with what you've tried and what happened so far.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for letting me know you don't work at MSFT, because they claimed that someone would reply back but it has been over a week almost.  I only get emails from MSFT India (or Wipro rather).  Hopefully we can figure out whether and how to use the new Azure App Service Mobile Apps versus the Old Deprecated way of some SDK2.2.2 or even older referenced in their examples.  I am on Skype at pliangca, so I hope you can connect.  Thks a lot.